# Copying selected ranges from different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I searched for a solution for this issue but couldn't find anything useful.

I have 5 worksheets in a Excel workbook; 2 of them are identical in formatting just like the other 3 are identical to themselves in formatting; stored data varies a lot from one to another.

I want to select from each worksheet some ranges matching 2 conditions and then copying them to a new workbook:

```
With shtSrc
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "s" Then
            c.Offset(0, -28).Resize(1, 8).Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 0).Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Unfortunately this results in copying just the cells from the selected (active) sheet rather than getting the cells from other sheets as well.

I also tried different codes (like For i = 1 to SheetCount) but what I got was getting copied 5 times the same cell from a single sheet and just ignoring the other sheets.

Here is the complete code. If anyone could help it would be great.

```
Sub FATTprova()
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date
Dim rng As Range
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim shCount As Integer
'shCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Set shtSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set shtDest = Workbooks.Add.Sheets("Foglio1")
startdate = CDate(InputBox("Inizio periodo dd/mm/yyyy"))
enddate = CDate(InputBox("Fine periodo dd/mm/yyyy"))

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'For i = 1 To shCount
    ws.Activate
    'shtSrc.Activate

If shtSrc.name = "CLIENTS" Or shtSrc.name = "SUPPLIERS" Then
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("AE:AE"), shtSrc.UsedRange)
Else
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("AD:AD"), shtSrc.UsedRange)
End If

With shtSrc
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "s" Then
            c.Offset(0, -28).Resize(1, 8).Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            c.Offset(0, 0).Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
End With

     Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
Set shtSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

You're telling Excel "ShtSrc" is always the activesheet and you never tell Excel that "ShtSrc" is changing with the loop.

I would just leave the "ws" variable, you dont need "ShtSrc" hehe

Changed your code a little:

```
    Sub FATTprova()
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim enddate As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim shCount As Integer

    'shCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set shtSrc = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set shtDest = Workbooks.Add.Sheets("Foglio1")
    startdate = CDate(InputBox("Inizio periodo dd/mm/yyyy"))
    enddate = CDate(InputBox("Fine periodo dd/mm/yyyy"))


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Select ' I WOULD RECOMMEND USING WITH STATEMENT

        MsgBox (ws.Name) ' THIS IS JUST TO MAKE SURE THE MACRO IS SELECTING EACH SHEET

    If ws.Name = "CLIENTS" Or ws.Name = "SUPPLIERS" Then
            Set rng = Application.Intersect(ws.Range("AE:AE"), ws.UsedRange)
        Else
            Set rng = Application.Intersect(ws.Range("AD:AD"), ws.UsedRange)

    With ws
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c.Value >= startdate And c.Value <= enddate And c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "s" Then
                c.Offset(0, -28).Resize(1, 8).Copy _
                    shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                c.Offset(0, 0).Copy _
                    shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    End If

         Next ws

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate,
I needed to add these lines as well to it to work:
`Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Set wbSrc = Workbooks("PROJECTS.xlsm")
For Each ws In wbSrc.Worksheets
wbSrc.Activate`


Otherwise it would have selected the new workbook as active and it wouldn't find anything. Errors came up but with this lines I fixed it. 
Thank you so much for your help!